# Testing neutrino magnetic moment in ultra-intense laser fields

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, laser-interaction

In some extended versions of the SM, Dirac neutrinos have a magnetic moment proportional to their mass. Could this be verified by studying neutrinos in ultra-intense laser field?

Comment: How are you envisioning the coupling of the neutrino magnetic moment to a laser?

Comment: you need netrino photon scattering  and your specific model in the calculations. see this for standard model calculations https://cds.cern.ch/record/321504/files/9703210.pdf . Then see if the crossection in some channel is enough to be detectable, then see if the difference between the different models ( with and without magnetic moment) is experimentally detectable. afaik these interactions have been of interest only for cosmological models.